# How to start jetty with HTTP2 if my app needs a param

Tags: java, linux, clojure, server, jetty

I'm using clojure. I need to start a program with port argument and at the same time I need to set HTTP2 for jetty server.

I'm using this command: `java -jar target/app-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar 4334 --add-to-startd=http2`

This doesn`t work - or better: it works, but without HTTP2.

My main function looks like this:

```
(defn -main [& [port]]
  (let [port (Integer. (or port (env :port) 5000))]
    (run-jetty (site #'app) {:port port :join? false})))
```

I'm using Java 8:

```
Java version "1.8.0_91"                   
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)       
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```